# Resizing Shiny's splitLayout()

Tags: css, r, shiny

Suppose we have a shiny app using `splitLayout()`. The two cells' width can be resized by adding style argument.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(HTML("test")),
  splitLayout(
    cellArgs = list(style='white-space: normal; resize: horizontal; min-width: 30vw; overflow: auto; max-width: 70vw;'),
    cellWidths = c("35%", "65%"),
    navbarPage(
      title = "Menu 1",
      p("wide page wide page")
    ),
    navbarPage(
      title = "Menu 2",
      p("wide page wide page")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is there something we can add so that increasing the width of one cell would decrease the another relatively to maintain the 100% width? In another word, prevent page to widen with x-scroll-bar appearing like below.
[image]

There was [another question here using js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61423343/resizing-column-widths-in-r-shiny-using-jquery/61427759?noredirect=1), but I am wondering if it is possible to keep it css. [This css-specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46044589/dynamically-resize-columns-in-css-grid-layout-with-mouse) seems to be using 1fr and grid system, but I am not sure how to incorporate this into `splitLayout()`. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know the CSS property `resize`. Is it used to resize with the mouse?

Comment: Something [like that](https://jsfiddle.net/6j10L3x2/1/) maybe? No JavaScript.

Comment: Ah no sorry, there is some JavaScript. But this is really nice.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent yes, it makes tiny thing that is draggable at bottom right! [I used this as reference][1] 
[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777504/css-resize-property-change-resize-icon-properties

Looks like it is not possible with css only :(